# How to change random filesystem label on USB OTG?

Tags: file-system, partitions, usb-on-the-go

I am without PC right now, but I need to Format USB Drive (to FAT32 or Ext4) with Samsung S8 (Android 9) and change label. But I can't find any app that can do this. I can format USB drive in Storage Menu, but without any options, it just gives it Random number name (I can see it in Total commander) and I think it's Ext4, but again no options. Is there any option to rename the Label?

I found they there is Aparted app (port of gparted) but it needs ROOT and also it gives random label.

I also tried to rename drive in Total commander, but it says it's ranamed, but in reality it has old label. Thanks for any help :).

Comment: Renaming of volumes usually requires root permission. As Android does not allow to set a label when formatting the volume any other app without root permission will not be able to change the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to create filesystem or set label without root access. Block devices in `/dev/block/` are created with ownership `0:0`, mode `0600`. Also apps aren't allowed to access SELinux context `device` or `block_device` set on `/dev` and `/dev/block`. You can use a rooted device or custom recovery like TWRP. Or use a PC (if available). On Linux and Android command-line is same.

> I need to Format USB Drive (to FAT32 or Ext4)

Use `mkfs.fat -F32 -n <LABEL>` or `mkfs.ext4 -L <LABEL>` to create filesystem with required label. Or later use `fatlabel`/`mlabel` or `e2label`/`tune2fs` to change label of an already created filesystem.

> I can format USB drive in Storage Menu, but without any options, it just gives it Random number name

The random number is not name (or label), it's filesystem UUID (32-digits long string on Linux filesystems like `ext2/3/4`) or Volume ID (8-digits long string on Windows filesystems like `NTFS`/`FAT32`/`exFAT`). Similarly GUID partitions have a PARTUUID and PARTLABEL (as reported by `blkid`).

USB OTG and external SD card is mounted by Volume Daemon (`vold`) on Android. Since Android 6 [by default `vold` uses filesystem UUID](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r50/model/PublicVolume.cpp#114) or VolumeID to create a mount path (which is [not an actual path](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526) in case of USB OTG) like [`/storage/[UUID]`](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config#android_6_0):

> *"Developers may continue to build paths dynamically or statically depending on their use case. Including the UUID in the path identifies each card to make location clearer for developers. (For example, `/storage/ABCD-1234/report.txt` is clearly a different file than `/storage/DCBA-4321/report.txt`.)"*

So even if you set label, whatever filesystem you choose, you will see the random number in path. However, like label, you can also set UUID/VolumeID of your choice (in case you want to retain same file path after formatting). Some file explorers, though, show filesystem label as storage name along with path.