# how to extend support for EXT4 file system for microSD cards in stock or non lineage / CyanogenMod ROMS

Tags: rom-flashing, mount, partitions, selinux, ext4

As  I am aware after `Android` 4.4 or some sort your storage card is no longer eXposed directly and needs to be carefully interfaced through specific `Mount` points that need to be aware through `vold`  system 

My question is given this situation and the fact that `ext4` is very complicated in terms of of access and especially with now `SeLinux` sitting on top of it
it is somehow still possible to render `ext4` support when it did not exist initialy as has been the case for `lineage` and previous similar OS's
that would be the case if the mount points  are created at boot time and then `vold` is made aware of them

**what I did**
since I am `rooted` ( `magisk` ) I use `su mount master` and mounted these manually but trying to then use `vold` failed because it was too late
I found some articles about how how this was achieved in earlier Android versions upto 5.
after 7.6 Android world has become even more paranoid on security and `seLINUX` couldn't have been more fussier
from 7.x onwards Android versions I would like to know if there is a definitive guide about how this can be done .I do not mind recompiling this feature in the kernel. this is a far more rewarding investment then trying to look for custom ROMs and moving away from stock just because you want `EXT4`support

so how do I I add 
`EXT4`support on stock  and similar ROMs
for Android versions > 7.x and do this the right way where all apps can access my partitions. all my partitions are 
`EXT4` this is quite in contrast to the the second `partition` `app2sd` approach that is used to save space. of course I have that as well but I have two more partitions used for `extSD` ( main external data storage partition ) and one devoted to to another app. totally 3
`EXT4` partitions . first one is the main data partition ,2nd is `app2sd` and third is a special partition devoted to one app. 
if it matters I am rooted on a Samsung device running stock nougat 7.x.

another thing that I observed and I will update the question accordingly is all of a sudden out of nowhere  partitions mounted under /storage are now read only earlier they were not so. I can still read write to them through /mnt/media_rw I wonder what went wrong because lot of apps depend on accessing my partitions through /storage Mount point.

So just to summarise here  are the questions:

- Mount multi `ext4` partitioned external card at boot time, as against manual mounting which I can do.
- Mount it the correct way with the right group ID, so that `vold` gets to know it has been mounted and all apps and process can freely access the partition.
- All external partitions under `/storage` suddenly became read only (internal memory partition is of course read write always). `tune2fs` confirmed that all partitions are clean. Why does this happen and how can it be fixed?

thanks for response. I put this question that sounded like a narrative since I did not have screenshots or logs at hand if that is what you meant in your opening comment in answer. So here's what I am trying to achieve but run into all kinds of errors.

 1) Mount `mmck1p2` to `/data/sdext2` and I keep getting error failed to mount ...`mmcblk1p2` on .....`invalid argument`  & another similar line 
 failed..... `/dev/block/vold/public` on .... invalid args. that is via `app2sd` and my `magisk` has global option turned on 
the same partition is already  mounted  at boot under `media_rw and storage`

`Bind mounting`  camera `DCIM` and many other folders in internal storage  fails  when   target  is `/storage/part#` & it  earlier worked well. My partitions are clean as per `tune2fs` report . What happened ?

Thanks again. Answering  your Q's here :

1) What are currently mounted filesystems (output of mount)? 

o/p is too big to fit in here. [PFA](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VLQmaGaRc2X95R7PQW1zeSyotOb2aZDC)

2) Output of /system/bin/id? 
for  normal user

```
uid=10112(u0_a112) gid=10112(u0_a112) groups=10112(u0_a112),1015(sdcard_rw),1023(media_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3003(inet),9997(everybody),50112(all_a112) context=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768
```

3) What command exactly did you use to mount mmck1p2 to /data/sdext2? 4) What command exactly did you use to bind mount DCIM folder?

```
1   mount -o,rw /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /storage/extsd
2   lp=/sdcard/logger.txt
4   ls./mnt/media_rw
5   ls /mnt/media_rw
6   mkdir -p $_/extsd
7   mount --bind /storage/extsd  $_
8   ls $_
```

with above run from terminal I am able to see files from terminal only. if run from `adb` I get the same situation 
. Thought `adb` would be persistent but ain't the case. 
after that I tried to invoke vold with the hope it would make my mount persistent and visible but no  luck there either

```
dreameltemtr:/ # /system/bin/vold
/system/bin/vold
Aborted
134|dreameltemtr:/ # /system/bin/vold --blkid_context=u:r:blkid:s0 --blkid_untrusted_context=u:r:blkid_untrusted:s0 --fsck_context=u:r:fsck:s0 --fsck_untrusted_context=u:
r:fsck_untrusted:s0
ntext=u:r:fsck:s0 --fsck_untrusted_context=u:r:fsck_untrusted:s0              <
SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:magisk:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.1.1_0003, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
```

also to `mount partition` # 2 via `app2sd`  there is a `mount` script that  the app writes to `/system/bin/etc or /data/app2sd` dir's depending on the opts you choose. It uses the similar approach except that 
-- I used its own binary for the bind mount functionality 
-- I will do periodic tests to see if certain partitions get mounted 
-- It will run these periodically ( kind of patched many scripts together  ) hoping that one will work 
-- I attempts to mount via block device  ( /`dev/block/mmcxxx`) as well as `vold` ( `/dev/block/vold/nnn`) 

 
Here is [that](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BpF7ywgb35bVEvqPahLv3b16irgYTJWD) script & you will see what I just said  . Again PFA since there is a ceiling to max chars on a post.

4) What are exact error messages? –
 exact messsages are 2 lines  from `app2sd` `gui` attention box

```
- Failed to mount /dev/block/ mmcblk1p2 to /data/sdext2 invalid argument <br>
- Failed to mount /dev/block/vold/public/179:34 to /data/sdext2 invalid argument<br>
```

On the last part where I cant write to external `partitions` mounted under `/storage` 
That instance of ROM install was abortive . It caused repeated `boot-loops` after 10 mins so I just restored my `Nandroid` backup. So I cant dig out more details .

Comment: You can format external SD card as `ext4` and mount it manually wherever you want. `ext4` support is present on every ROM - stock or custom - since the first release of Android. What exactly your question is?

Comment: Thank you for responding Irfan I can found it manually as I have written so

Comment: Thank you for responding Irfan I can found it manually as I have written so . There are 3 questions sorry if it was not clear 1 ) it needs to mount at boot time and read write 2 ) the mounting information needs to be transferred so as to say to v o l d process so all other processes and apps can access that external data storage partition

Comment: 3 ) another thing that I observed and I will update the question accordingly is all of a sudden out of nowhere  partitions mounted under /storage are now read only earlier they were not so. I can still read write to them through /mnt/media_rw I wonder what went wrong because lot of apps depend on accessing my partitions through /storage Mount point.

Comment: please clarify if you looking for non-rooted solution. i guess your problem isn't the file system it is more related to app permissions. have a look at https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: @user1874594 1) What are currently mounted filesystems (output of `mount`)? 2) Output of `/system/bin/id`? 3) What command exactly did you use to mount `mmck1p2` to `/data/sdext2`? 4) What command exactly did you use to bind mount DCIM folder? 5) What are exact error messages?

Comment: THanks again Irfan Theres a mount script that I will put out in the question. and also o/p of mount

Comment: added more details you asked for Irfan- Thanks !

Comment: @ALex thank you again. This ROM is `permissive` right out of the box

Comment: thanks  folks for your help. I finally got the mounting  to happen using

Comment: thanks  folks for your help. I finally got the mounting  to happen using `fbind magisk` module but it would not happen straight away. had to open the the script which was full of functions and one of the functions looked for Mount media read write  as a mountaing pt In `/proc /partitions`.  & it never came out to be true with a time out of 1800 s.this function had to be to tweaked so that the result will be true when ,`/mnt` was mounted  and then the Mounting would happen.  hopefully the time I have invested in all this will pay off with this same module being used every time I  face this !

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I understand your question fully. It's not clear what and how you have tried so far and faced what constraints or limitations in achieving what you want to. But precisely answering your questions:

> Mount multi `ext4` partitioned external card at boot time, as against manual mounting which I can do

Mounting external SD card is handled by `vold`. You can disable that in `fstab` and define an `init` service or put an `init.d` script to mount the partitions on boot the way you want.

> Mount it the correct way with the right group ID, so that `vold` gets to know it has been mounted and all apps and process can freely access the partition

Since Android 6, in Portable Storage mode, `vold` mounts external SD card at `/mnt/media_rw/[UUID]` and then emulates that to `/storage/[UUID]`. Apps with `WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE` permission (which is mapped to GID `media_rw (1023)`) have filesystem level write access to external SD card. But third party apps cannot write to SD card because the said permission has `signature|privileged` protection level. Emulation makes it possible for apps to read whole SD card but write only to their private directories. Also apps may use Android APIs (like SAF) to save files on SD card. See details in [How to move files to external SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526)

This whole phenomenon is deeply integrated in Android framework - Java and native. So if you want to change this behavior, you need to modify Android source and rebuild ROM. Or don't rely on `vold` and mount partitions yourself with correct permissions as I mentioned earlier.

> All external partitions under `/storage` suddenly became read only

There can be multiple possible reasons, you can check kernel log or Android log to see what exactly happens when you do `mount -o rw,remount`. Mounting read-only can be a sign of errors due to flash chip degradation. Or may be the partition(s) simply reached their maximum mount count, so you need to run `fsck`.

Comment: THanks for replying. I gave these details you asked for much as I could  dig em out.  What I want to get from all this is on a `ROM`  that does not support `ext4`  for  sdcard  like CM or Lineage , how can I have this functionality so that every time I dont have to flash a new Lineage ROM & then deal with its other short comings. Hope i am clear by now. Now for this instance I dont see /etc/init.d folder there is a init folder & even if I remount rw. Reboot will del scripts . i can put them in xbin but not sure if they will be executed.