# How to specify the directory path on external memory card?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, file-system, redmi

An app currently saves files to "mydir" on the internal memory:

/storage/emulated/0/**mydir**

Instead, I want the files saved onto external memory card, but I am unable to figure out what is the right path. The attempts below do not work:

/SanDisk SD card/mydir

/storage/SanDisk SD card/mydir

/storage/emulated/SanDisk SD card/mydir

Android 9 , Redmi 8

"SanDisk SD card" comes from a file manager app, not sure if the card is to be specified by this or something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save files to external SD card on a non-rooted Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175738/how-to-save-files-to-external-sd-card-on-a-non-rooted-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
/storage/36E2-14BB/
```

this is what stands for the external microSD card,

```
/storage/36E2-14BB/mydir
```

...and this is for my own custom directory on the microSD.

(I got the `/storage/36E2-14BB/` from an app where the available folder options were listed in a drop-down menu. Otherwise, no clue how to arrive to the `36E2-14BB` and it is is unique or universal to each microSD cards.)