# How to find exact file path to an external microSD card?

Tags: file-system

Is there a way to find out the path of files from a microSD card that is inserted into any Android phone?

---

**Related investigation:**

From here, [How to specify the directory path on external memory card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/223712/how-to-specify-the-directory-path-on-external-memory-card) , it seems like the problem was solved, using an unspecified app that pointed to the right direction. (implying a tool can exist for that purpose)

From here, [How to save files to external SD card on a non-rooted Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175738/how-to-save-files-to-external-sd-card-on-a-non-rooted-android) , it implies `/storage/[UUID]/`, but it wasn't clear how exactly to figure out that UUID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround.

Using the [SD Card Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doionline.sdcardmanager) app, I looked at the Info of a folder in my microSD card while its connected to my phone, and was able to see my own particular UUID in `/storage/[UUID]`, for example, `/storage/1234-5678`.

I then confirmed the UUID in a separate app that asked for it, i.e.:
`/storage/1234-5678/my_own_folder`, which was ended up being successful found and used.