# How via "a script" to move files (pics and videos from Camera) from phone to SD card?

Tags: automation, scripts

A user may have a slow SD card. So taking pictures and videos on internal storage solves the problem nicely. It has 100GB. However, it can get big. And the SD card is 256GB. So the user wants to free up space and (once a week or month) move pics and videos to SD card. That is what is desired. Please advice.

In windows, I would create a .bat file and put to desktop and execute when I need it.

something like

```
copy c:/fast_storage/DCIM/Camera/*.* c:/large_storage/DCIM
```

How can I put a similar script on my Android home screen?  (not a rooted phone). It can be inside some program that supports such simple script. (but not tasker or some too fancy solution that drains battery and runs all the time). The copy action is on demand (not scheduled).

It seems silly to do the steps repeatedly manually and not use a script approach. Can android do this?

Comment: for pulling files from phone to pc check [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) or [adb-sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync) for shell scripting check [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28231179)

Comment: Use Termux widget to place a shortcut to a script on home screen. But Termux cannot access SD card directly (except its private directories) due to Android's restrictions. So you have to deal with that. I've an app of my own which I use to execute scripts on given schedule. It doesn't run all the time and doesn't drain battery. It's not very fancy but I can share if you are interested. However, the problem of SD card restrictions remains for any app not using Android's SAF: [How to save files to external SD card on a non-rooted Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526).