# How can I download a file with the Google Drive program directly to my phone's SD card?

Tags: downloading, google-drive

I use Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 10. How can I download a file with the Google Drive program directly to my phone's SD card? By default files are downloaded to my phone's internal storage.

Comment: If Google Drive app doesn't have an option, you can't. Plus, apps can only write to their private directories on external SD cards, even with Storage permission granted: [How to save files to external SD card on a non-rooted Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526). Things are getting more difficult with Scoped Storage concept on Android 11+

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer

Comment: Access to Google Drive can be added to apps directly (no need to go through the Google Drive app). For example there is an add-on for tasker that allows upload/download tasks with Google Drive.